# How to remove this about:blank#blocked and make my function work?

Tags: javascript

I use this code below: (Django python)

```
<a href="javascript:{document:getElementById('logout').submit()}" class="sign-out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
```

and when I click on it, nothing happens. But if i open it in a ne tab, google chrome says about:blank#blocked. How do I fix this

Comment: Don't use `href` to execute JS code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem is caused by usage error.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('logout').submit();
  }
</script>  
<a href="javascript:myFunction()" class="sign-out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
```

It should work that way.

Comment: This didn't work. Probably because I changed document:getElementById as document.getElementById. That's how I solved the problem. Thanks again.